# Using changePage to Open a Dialog - Data object not sent

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
$.mobile.changePage("verify.aspx", { transition: "pop", role: "dialog", data: $("#form1").serialize() });
```

I'm using the above syntax to open a dialog box and in trying to send the form data via the data argument, nothing is passed.

This is what's being passed in the query string when I open the dialog:

```
#&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog
```

(as a side note, this call is originating from a button within another dialog, thus the two ui-state=dialog's)

As you can see, no form data. Any ideas what I can do to persist the data in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Found that the data-url attribute of the dialog you request is injected w/ the relative url.

By doing something like:

```
$("#dialog").on("pagebeforecreate", function (evt) {
            var urlObj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl($(this).attr("data-url"));
```

Will give you access to the url and thus the proper query string values.